How to compile and install latest qpdfview pdf reader?
My system environment is Ubuntu 20.04. I downloaded latest source code for qpdfview (0.5 version as of now) from: https://launchpad.net/qpdfview/+download
Installation instruction in README file:

It depends on libQtCore, libQtGui. It also depends on libQtSvg,
libQtSql, libQtDBus, libcups, resp. libz if SVG, SQL, D-Bus, CUPS,
resp. SyncTeX support is enabled. It also depends on libmagic if Qt
version 4 is used and libmagic support is enabled. The PDF plug-in
depends on libQtCore, libQtXml, libQtGui and libpoppler-qt4 or
libpoppler-qt5. The PS plug-in depends on libQtCore, libQtGui and
libspectre. The DjVu plug-in depends on libQtCore, libQtGui and
libdjvulibre. The Fitz plug-in depends on libQtCore, libQtGui and
libmupdf.
The Fitz plug-in is currently considered experimental due to the lack
of a maintainer. It also lacks support for various features, e.g.
meta-data, encryption, text search, text extraction, form fields and
annotations.
It is built using "lrelease qpdfview.pro", "qmake qpdfview.pro" and
"make". It is installed using "make install". The installation paths
are defined in "qpdfview.pri".

Installed Qt5 tools and dependencies for qpdfview:
sudo apt install libcups2-dev libmupdf-dev libdjvulibre-dev libspectre-dev libpoppler-qt5-dev qttools5-dev-tools qtbase5-dev qt5-qmake cmake

Compiling pwdfview with the following commands:
lrelease qpdfview.pro
qmake qpdfview.pro
make

The last make command produces the following output with error:
qpdfview-0.5$ make

( test -e Makefile.pdf-plugin || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile.pdf-plugin qpdfview-0.5/pdf-plugin.pro ) && make -f Makefile.pdf-plugin 
make[1]: Entering directory 'qpdfview-0.5'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'qpdfview-0.5'
( test -e Makefile.ps-plugin || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile.ps-plugin qpdfview-0.5/ps-plugin.pro ) && make -f Makefile.ps-plugin 
make[1]: Entering directory 'qpdfview-0.5'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'qpdfview-0.5'
( test -e Makefile.djvu-plugin || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile.djvu-plugin qpdfview-0.5/djvu-plugin.pro ) && make -f Makefile.djvu-plugin 
make[1]: Entering directory 'qpdfview-0.5'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'qpdfview-0.5'
( test -e Makefile.image-plugin || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile.image-plugin qpdfview-0.5/image-plugin.pro ) && make -f Makefile.image-plugin 
make[1]: Entering directory 'qpdfview-0.5'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
make[1]: Leaving directory 'qpdfview-0.5'
( test -e Makefile.application || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile.application qpdfview-0.5/application.pro ) && make -f Makefile.application 
make[1]: Entering directory 'qpdfview-0.5'
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o qpdfview objects/settings.o objects/pluginhandler.o objects/shortcuthandler.o objects/rendertask.o objects/tileitem.o objects/pageitem.o objects/thumbnailitem.o objects/presentationview.o objects/searchmodel.o objects/searchitemdelegate.o objects/searchtask.o objects/miscellaneous.o objects/documentlayout.o objects/documentview.o objects/printdialog.o objects/settingsdialog.o objects/fontsdialog.o objects/helpdialog.o objects/recentlyusedmenu.o objects/recentlyclosedmenu.o objects/bookmarkmenu.o objects/bookmarkdialog.o objects/bookmarkmodel.o objects/database.o objects/mainwindow.o objects/application.o objects/main.o objects/synctex_parser.o objects/synctex_parser_utils.o objects/signalhandler.o objects/qrc_icons.o objects/moc_settings.o objects/moc_model.o objects/moc_pluginhandler.o objects/moc_shortcuthandler.o objects/moc_rendertask.o objects/moc_pageitem.o objects/moc_thumbnailitem.o objects/moc_presentationview.o objects/moc_searchmodel.o objects/moc_searchitemdelegate.o objects/moc_searchtask.o objects/moc_miscellaneous.o objects/moc_documentview.o objects/moc_printdialog.o objects/moc_settingsdialog.o objects/moc_fontsdialog.o objects/moc_helpdialog.o objects/moc_recentlyusedmenu.o objects/moc_recentlyclosedmenu.o objects/moc_bookmarkmodel.o objects/moc_bookmarkmenu.o objects/moc_bookmarkdialog.o objects/moc_database.o objects/moc_mainwindow.o objects/moc_application.o objects/moc_signalhandler.o   -lz /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Svg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Concurrent.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so -lpthread   
/usr/bin/ld: objects/documentview.o: in function `qpdfview::DocumentView::printUsingCUPS(QPrinter*, qpdfview::PrintOptions const&, int, int)':
documentview.cpp:(.text+0xb56a): undefined reference to `cupsGetDests'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xb5ab): undefined reference to `cupsGetDest'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xb65a): undefined reference to `cupsAddOption'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xb769): undefined reference to `cupsAddOption'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xb803): undefined reference to `cupsAddOption'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xb88b): undefined reference to `cupsAddOption'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xb8d3): undefined reference to `cupsAddOption'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xb961): undefined reference to `cupsGetOption'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xb9e7): undefined reference to `cupsGetOption'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xba50): undefined reference to `cupsAddOption'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xba90): undefined reference to `cupsGetOption'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xbd1b): undefined reference to `cupsPrintFile'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xbdd1): undefined reference to `cupsFreeDests'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xbdde): undefined reference to `cupsFreeOptions'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xbdfa): undefined reference to `cupsFreeDests'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xbe07): undefined reference to `cupsFreeOptions'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xbe69): undefined reference to `cupsGetPPD'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xbe7f): undefined reference to `ppdOpenFile'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xbe9c): undefined reference to `ppdFindOption'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xbf0a): undefined reference to `cupsAddOption'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xbf17): undefined reference to `ppdClose'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xbf81): undefined reference to `cupsAddOption'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xbfa5): undefined reference to `cupsAddOption'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xbfcd): undefined reference to `cupsAddOption'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xc099): undefined reference to `cupsAddOption'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xc29d): undefined reference to `cupsAddOption'
/usr/bin/ld: objects/documentview.o:documentview.cpp:(.text+0xc2c5): more undefined references to `cupsAddOption' follow
/usr/bin/ld: objects/documentview.o: in function `qpdfview::DocumentView::printUsingCUPS(QPrinter*, qpdfview::PrintOptions const&, int, int)':
documentview.cpp:(.text+0xc518): undefined reference to `cupsLastErrorString'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xc657): undefined reference to `cupsLastErrorString'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xc6e1): undefined reference to `cupsFreeDests'
/usr/bin/ld: documentview.cpp:(.text+0xc788): undefined reference to `cupsAddOption'
/usr/bin/ld: objects/documentview.o: in function `qpdfview::DocumentView::printUsingCUPS(QPrinter*, qpdfview::PrintOptions const&, int, int) [clone .cold]':
documentview.cpp:(.text.unlikely+0x955): undefined reference to `ppdClose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile.application:358: qpdfview] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory 'qpdfview-0.5'
make: *** [Makefile:164: sub-application-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2

According to this answer it seems that the problem in the source code. But I'm not sure. May be I missed some additional dependency. Will continue to investigate but probably someone already successfully compiled this program?

Old related question: How to install qpdfview 0.4.14?

There are several possible reasons for errors like this: (1) the library API has changed so that it is no longer compatible with the project source (2) the linker is searching libraries in the wrong order (3) the link command simply isn't linking the library. In this case it appears the problem is (3) - I see no mention of libcups on the g++ command line.

@steeldriver Great! You comment is straight to the point. With adding  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so to LIBS qpdfview compiled successfully. The problem was in sources, not in environment. Add an answer and I will accept it.

@steeldriver Details: need to add /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so to LIBS parameter in Makefile.application file: LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) -lz /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Svg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Concurrent.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so -lpthread

After compilation to install qpdfview: make install

@steeldriver Ok, I will put my answer. I'm not an expert in c++. I've tried runs with: make 'LIBS=-lcups', LIBS=-lcups make, make 'LIBS=-libcups', LIBS=-libcups make, LIBS=libcups make, LIBS=libcups.so make, LIBS=-libcups.so make, put to LIBS prop in the config file libcups without path. And libcups.so. Nothing is working.

With steeldriver's help I've found out that the problem is in the sources (or in the installation instruction), not in the environment.
Before calling make need to add /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so library to LIBS parameter in Makefile.application file:
LIBS = $(SUBLIBS) -lz /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5PrintSupport.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Svg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Concurrent.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so -lpthread
With this compilation passed successfully.
Config for installation is in qpdfview.pri file.
To install compiled qpdfview:
sudo make install

